# Troubles with unresolved dependencies on Debian 6 Sqeeze

Tags: debian, apt, dependencies, nginx

I'm working with a VirtualBox 4.2.14 VM and Debian 6 Sqeeze as guest system and trying to (re-)install Nginx, but it's not working:

```
root@devmv:~# apt-get install nginx
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nginx : Depends: nginx-full but it is not going to be installed or
                  nginx-light but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

Or in the same in Synaptic Package Manager:

[image]

`aptitude` provides more information about the missing dependencies:

```
root@devmv:~# aptitude install nginx
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nginx nginx-common{a} nginx-full{ab} 
0 packages upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 580 kB/645 kB of archives. After unpacking 1,391 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  nginx-full: Depends: libgeoip1 (>= 1.4.8+dfsg) but 1.4.7~beta6+dfsg-1 is installed.
              Depends: libpcre3 (>= 8.10) but 8.02-1.1 is installed.
              Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.1) which is a virtual package.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     nginx [Not Installed]                              
2)     nginx-full [Not Installed]                         



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

Usually `apt-get` should install not only the package, but also recursively its dependencies, right? What's goning wrong here?

---

EDIT:

**/etc/apt/sources.list**

```
# 

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.6 _Squeeze_ - Official amd64 NETINST Binary-1 20120930-15:53]/ squeeze main

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.6 _Squeeze_ - Official amd64 NETINST Binary-1 20120930-15:53]/ squeeze main

deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main

deb http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main

# squeeze-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates main

# For Nginx & PHP
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org stable all
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze-php54 all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze-php54 all

# psmisc 22.16
deb http://ftp.at.debian.org/debian-backports/ squeeze-backports main
```

**/etc/apt/sources.list.d** is empty.

Comment: Can you post the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` (and anything in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`).

Comment: And the output of `apt-cache policy` for the problematic packages?

Comment: You're not using pure debian repositories, you're also using backports and a specific nginx repository.  Apt will only go so far when installing packages, especially if the package has a newly added dependency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're installing `nginx` from a non-debian repository, but it requires libraries at a later version than you have installed, which also aren't available in the debian repositories (for squeeze, because they're wheezy versions).

Your entry,

```
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org stable all
```

is giving you Wheezy versions, since stable=wheezy.  You should either move everything to Wheezy, or use **oldstable** instead of **stable**.  (In fact, it's better to stick with release names like **squeeze**, rather than **stable** these days).